# Bash shell script html css

Tags: html, css, shell

```
while read row do
    echo "<tr>" >> $file
    for valore in $row 
    do
        echo "<td>$valore</td>" >> $file
    done
        echo "</tr>" >> $file
done < alunni.txt
    echo "</table>" >> $file
```

When I execute this fraction of code it gives me this error:

```
./table_html.csv: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
./table_html.csv: line 36: `            echo "<td>$valore</td>" >> $file'
```

How do I fix it?

I'm not very good with shell scripts, that's why I can not think of anything else.

Comment: I think all that's missing is a `;` or a linebreak after `row` in the first line. The unquoted expansion of `$row` in line 3 can go wrong in many ways, but without seeing the contents of `alunni.txt`, there's no way to say how to do it instead.

Answer (score 0):

(Ah I was working on this when the alarm for the oven went off) what I wanted to say was it's just the "do" in the wrong place after the while. So here's your code restated (with a file="filename" added to get it working):

```
file="test2.html"
while read row 
do
    echo "<tr>" >> $file
    for valore in $row 
    do
        echo "<td>$valore</td>" >> $file
    done
        echo "</tr>" >> $file
done < alunni.txt
    echo "</table>" >> $file
```

So it was just a line break before the do is all you needed :-)